# Override Eclipse File > Save Action

Tags: eclipse, file, save, overriding, eclipse-rcp

I am trying to override the Eclipse File > Save menu action to add some functionality.
I have tried the following things

a) Create a new action and add it to the global action handler

`actionBars.setGlobalActionHandler(ActionFactory.SAVE.getId(), mySaveAction);
actionRegistry.registerAction(action);`

b) Create a new handler and override the save command

```
<extension point="org.eclipse.ui.handlers">
<handler commandId="org.eclipse.ui.file.save"
  class="com.diagrams.ui.SaveFileHandler">
<enabledWhen> 
  <with variable="activePartId">
  <equals 
    value="com.diagrams.editors.MultiPageEditor" />
  </with>
</enabledWhen>
<activeWhen>
  <with variable="activePartId">
  <equals 
  value="com.diagrams.editors.MultiPageEditor" />
  </with>
</activeWhen>
</handler>
</extension>
```

With both these approaches I have been able to override the Keyboard Ctrl+S functionality but the "File > Save" menu seem to work differently.

Would really appreciate any help, Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In an RCP application, you can contribute the Save action in your ActionBarAdvisor.  This also registers the action so it is available from the save command.

But as a plugin in the Eclipse IDE, the IDE provides the ActionBarAdvisor and hooks up the Save action in the File menu.  Because that's not technically a command (Actions are a step above an SWT.Selection listener) that's why you can't override the File>Save action.

However, each part provides its own save implementation, so you can do whatever you want in your MultiPageEditor.

The other option is to use `org.eclipse.ui.commands.ICommandService.addExecutionListener(IExecutionListener)` and add an IExecutionListener (or IEL2).  That can listen for the save command, the ID is declared in `org.eclipse.ui.IWorkbenchCommandConstants`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Paul. My main motive for the query was that I needed to differentiate the save being called from the File > Save and when called due to a file being closed. I am for now able to accomplish my task why overriding the onSave and isSaveNeededOnClose methods in the editor. But I will keep in mind the listener approach if needed in the future.

Comment: Is this still true? It doesn't seem to work for me at all (on Indigo) :(

Comment: yes, it works on Indigo (although not currently in Juno, that's coming)

Answer (score 0):

It might have something to do with the activePartId being different when the main menu is selected versus a keystroke or using the right-click menu.  Have you looked at other extension points?

Comment: From what I have figured the activePartId should be the same. Moreover I have other actions(which I have created) which show up in the File menu for the same activePartId.                      I looked at the command and handler extension points and this looked as the correct way to go. Is there another extension point I should be using?